# SQL query performance issues

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below SQL query that is taking an inordinate amount of time to run. Indexes have been added to all of the join fields in each table. Record counts for each table are as follows:

> CRM.ASSET_PLUS:15,766,000
>
> CRM.EMPLOYEE: 44,300
>
> CRM.ACCOUNT: 1,180,000
>
> CRM.DATA_NOTIFICATIONS: 500
>
> CRM.PROD_INT: 87,800

What can I do to make this query more efficient?

```
SELECT D.NAME AS UP_ACCOUNT_NAME,
   B.FIRST_NAME,
   B.LAST_NAME
FROM CRM.ASSET_PLUS A, 
 CRM.EMPLOYEE B, 
 CRM.ACCOUNT C,
 CRM.ACCOUNT D, 
 CRM.DATA_NOTIFICATIONS E, 
 CRM.PROD_INT F
WHERE A.STATUS IN ('Active', 'Pending Install')
  AND E.PROD_DEF_OLD = F.X_ITEM_NUMBER
  AND F.ROW_ID = A.PRODUCT_ID
  AND C.UP_ACCOUNT_ID = D.ACCOUNT_ID
  AND C.ACCOUNT_ID = A.LOCATION_ACCOUNT_ID
  AND D.MANAGER_ID = B.EMPLOYEE_ID
  AND UPPER(D.NAME) LIKE '%BP%'
GROUP BY D.NAME,
     B.FIRST_NAME,
     B.LAST_NAME
```

Comment: What is your RDBMS? Assuming you have proper indexes, beside the fact that your `join`'s are non-readable when you are doing them implicitly, I found no issue with your current query. What performance problems are you experiencing?

Comment: And if it's SQL Server, then show us the Query Plan (actual is preferred over estimated).

Comment: It's an Oracle database. It just takes a very long time to run, around 5 minutes.

Comment: And what is the point of grouping if there is no aggregation function? You might as well use `DISTINCT`

Comment: Is it any faster without the last AND statement in the WHERE clause?

Comment: How selective are those two predicates? What row count from the two tables match them? You also need to post the explain plan in order to get meaningful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid off that group by.
You are just selecting (account join employee) and using all other tables to filter it. You can get duplicated result and that's the only reason why you are using that group by.

But that's not necessary if you rewrite the query to move all other tables to the where clause.

I created a example to demonstrate it.
and try to write explicit joins to separate filter and join predicates.
[example using SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/49e2a/7)

Answer (score 0):

1)
Get rid of this if you can:
AND UPPER(D.NAME) LIKE '%BP%'

1.1)If posible, do Not allow user to put % in front of a like clause (because it implies full table scan)

Note: You can allow it if you use only one at the beginning, by storing a computed column with reverse(d.name) and using D.reversedname LIKE 'PB%' instead of D.name like 'BP%' . The key here is that the % must be in the end and not in the beginning.

Check this out
https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/like-performance-tuning
create index for d.name

1.2 do NOT use UPPER -> either:

->change the column collation to a case insensitive one (ending in _CI) and remove the UPPER (easier)
or 
->use a computed column to precalculate this UPPER(D.NAME) in a new PERSISTED column and use that column instead in the clause. If you use this solution, do not forget to create an index for that new column.

2) create indexes for all foreign keys used in the query / joins

3) if possible , require minimum chars for that LIKE, in order to reduce the number of possible results.

Answer (score -1):

First thing that I see here is that you use `INNER JOIN` and then `WHERE` statement. 
Use syntax `table1 as t1 INNER JOIN table2 as t2 ON t1.key = t2.key`.

So in where you will have only `UPPER(D.NAME) LIKE '%BP%' AND A.STATUS IN ('Active', 'Pending Install')` condition. It will allow DBMS to do lots of optimizations.

Also instead of `INNER JOIN` try to do `LEFT JOIN` where it possible. It will significantly decrease amount of rows in temp table.

Comment: In Oracle this is unlikely to produce any change to the execution plan, and hence to the performance. Changing from inner to outer joins could change the result set, so would not be desirable -- not sure what you mean by the temp table comment, also.